# document.findElementByXPath fails

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, robotframework

I am tring to find element using:

```
self.s2l.execute_javascript(
    'document.getElement(By.XPath"{}")[0].scrollBy(0,{})'.format(
        element,
        new_position
    )
```

Got error:

> JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: missing ) after argument list

When I use:

```
self.s2l.execute_javascript(
     'document.getElementsByClassName("{}")[0].scrollBy(0,{})'.format(
        element,
        new_position
    )
```

Works and test pass.

Could you please help what went wront with Xpath?

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. _Could you please help what went wront with Xpath?_ Did you read the error message?

Answer (score 1):

You need parentheses around the argument to `By.XXX()`. Also, there's a `.` between `By` and the type of locator.

And you have unbalanced parentheses -- you're missing the `)` that matches the `(` after `self.s21.execute_javascript`. (I'm not sure why your second example doesn't have the same problem).

```
self.s2l.execute_javascript(
    'document.findElement(By.xpath("{}"))[0].scrollBy(0,{})'.format(
        element,
        new_position
    )
)
```

Also, `xpath` is lowercase in JavaScript Selenium.

if the XPath expression contains quotes, don't use the same kind of quotes that delimit the XPath, and then escape them to keep them from ending the string that contains the JavaScript.

```
self.s21.execute_javascript(
    'document.findElement(By.xpath("//div[starts-with(@class,\'ReactVirtualize\')]"))[0].scrollBy(0,8000)'.format(
        element,
        new_position
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks Bamar for the reply. still getting the same problem.
  Executing JavaScript:
document.findElement(By.xpath("//div[starts-with(@class,"ReactVirtualize")]"))[0].scrollBy(0,8000)
Without any arguments.
JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: missing ) after argument list

Comment: You're missing the `)` at the end.

Comment: You need to escape the double quotes that are inside the xpath expression.

Comment: error:  JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Unexpected token '}'